# Backtesting Option Strategies

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to implement the Optopsy code for backtesting option strategies.

I get as far as pip install optopsy on the instructions and then I'm not sure how to implement the next line:

```
python strategies/sample_strategy.py
```

Also, which folder do you save the data file in?

For this line

```
data = op.get(FILE, SPX_FILE_STRUCT, prompt=False)
```

do you put the actual file name and location?

Website link to the code is below:

https://pypi.org/project/optopsy/

Thank you, RK

Comment: Since you mention the “next step” in some instructions or a tutorial, can you provide a link to the tutorial you’re following?

Comment: Website link to the code is:

https://pypi.org/project/optopsy/      I have installed python, miniconda, panda and optopsy. Following the instructions on the website, pip install optopsy step I completed, cannot figure out the python strategies/sample strategy.py part so i skipped that for now. Import step seems to work and the next define data structure seems to work. Then I cannot figure out the last part. Might have something to do with where i save the actual data file and the name of the file itself. Thank you, Rahim K

Comment: Got it, you have to write the main script. RK

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble from the posted example in the early days of Optopsy development. The snippet was incomplete. The author Michael Chu has since improved and published his source code.
Try this module and corresponding data from:

https://github.com/michaelchu/optopsy.

It is the same data file that you have. "./data/Sample_SPX_20151001_to_20151030.csv"
and the code you started with is now complete, working great and found here

https://github.com/michaelchu/optopsy/blob/master/samples/spx_singles_example.py

This Optopsy is a phenomenal library. The Optopsy v 2.0 is now the current.

Other Python backtesting libraries bt., backtrader, pyalgotrade, quantopian, zipline and pysystemtrade account for underlying backtesting and frustratingly suffer from insufficient testing available for options.

Feel free to reach out if you have a question I am actively using Optopsy works great with v3.7 and the output is straight to the point displaying your results in a pleasant formant.

Yes to your question with line

data = op.get(FILE, SPX_FILE_STRUCT, prompt=False)

You do need your current directory. I think you want something like this:

```
def filepath():
curr_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

return os.path.join("./your_directory/sample_spx_strategy.py" , "SPX_20151001_to_20151030.csv")
```

I find I need to change all backslashes to forward slashes when you copy paste your full path.

-Cloihdna